# Is there a way to control flow of promises in linear call order?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I still don't have tight grip on promises. Say I have a code:

```
selected.eq(i)   // blink
    .fadeOut( 200 ).delay( 50 ).fadeIn( 400 )
    .delay( 100 )
    .fadeOut( 200 ).delay( 50 ).fadeIn( 400 );
```

and later I call:

```
selected.unbind('click')
    .promise().done(function ()
        {
            selected.fadeOut(500);
        });
```

It works as excepted -- once the blinking is done, the last `fadeOut` kicks in. But when I do the blinking via plugin (with setup to use jQuery animation) so my entire first part is just one call:

```
selected.eq(i).modernBlink({ 
    duration: 750,
    iterationCount: 3,
    auto: true}
    );
```

the body of blink is:

```
ModernBlink.prototype._fallbackAnimation = function _fallbackAnimation( iterationCount ) {
    var self = this,
    duration = this.options.duration / 2;

    if ( iterationCount > 0 || iterationCount === 'infinite' ) {
        iterationCount = iterationCount === "infinite" ? "infinite" : iterationCount - 1;

    this.el.animate( { 'opacity': 0 }, duration ).promise().done( function() {
        self.el.animate( { 'opacity': 1 }, duration );
        self._fallbackAnimation( iterationCount );
    });
}
};
```

so it is recursive call based on `promise` as well. The outcome is different -- after first iteration from `blink` my code kicks in, because my `promise` won.

The visual effect is -- blink, fade out (mine part), keep blinking.

**My question is** -- how to tell jQuery the `blink` promises are more important than mine?

NOTE: I cannot attach directly the second part to the first part, because they are scattered in code, and sometimes the first part is not executed.

*The code of blink comes from [Modern Blink](https://github.com/leonderijke/jQuery-Modern-Blink) by leonderijke. MB was used here as example!*

UPDATE: Big picture, I don't know if this helpful or not, but anyway:

```
if (Environment.Mode=='blink') // my private settings variable
    call_blink(); // part 1, presented above
call_fade_out(); // part 2, presented above
```

This is why, I cannot chain them. I have similar "configuration" of code used some more, so I would like to understand it, and use it here and in other places.

Comment: How many elements does `this.el` target? only 1?

Comment: @KevinB, here, 2 or 1.

Comment: I mean in this specific case, in your second example. Is the plugin acting on each element individually, or all of them as a whole. The answer to that will affect the outcome of the promise. Looking at the source, it appears to act on each element individually.

Comment: *"how to tell jQuery the blink promises are more important than mine?"* that doesn't make sense. Promises don't get priority, you just choose which one you want to listen to.

Comment: @KevinB, in real code -- the first part is called SOMETIMES. And if it is called it is called on the one element of the two elements collection. The second part of code is called ALWAYS, on this two elements collection. In other words, I always shade out collection, and from time to time I blink the first element of it.

Comment: Can you show a little bit more of how you would use the plugin version?

Comment: @KevinB, I updated the question, is this what you had in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make `modernBlink` return a promise that represents the result you are after - the end of the blinking. It simply is impossible to intercept animations that will only be chained in the future. The plugin you're using should return a promise, or at least provide a callback; if it doesn't to that you'll need to use a different one or fork it.

In your case, the blink method will need to repeatedly chain itself to the promise by using [`then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/):

```
ModernBlink.prototype._fallbackAnimation = function(iterationCount) {
    var self = this,
    duration = this.options.duration / 2;

    if (iterationCount === 'infinite' || iterationCount-- > 0) {
        return this.el.animate({'opacity': 0}, duration).promise()
        .then(function() {
            return self.el.animate({'opacity': 1}, duration).promise();
        })
        .then(function() {
            return self._fallbackAnimation(iterationCount);
        });
    } else {
        return this;
    }
};
```

Now, your big picture might look like this:

```
if (Environment.Mode=='blink')
    var step1 = new ModernBlink()._fallbackAnimation(5);
else
    var step1 = jQuery.when(undefined);

var step2 = step1.then(call_fade_out);
```

Comment: Ah, I see the light -- the second "step1" in big picture! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Try utilizing the [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend) event

```
$.each(["webkit", "moz", "MS", "o", ""], function (k, v) {
    selected[0].addEventListener(v !== "" ? v + "AnimationEnd" : "animationend"
    , function (e) {
        $(this).unbind('click')
            .promise().done(function (el) {
            el.fadeOut(500);
            console.log("done")
        });
    })
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/x7gqb1g4/

---

An alternative approach ; "infinite" loop by maintaining `count !== 0` ,  "stop" by calling `.stop()` , `clearQueue()` setting `.data()` flag

```
    // v2
    // `d` : duration , `count` : iteration
    (function ($) {
    $.fn.blink = blink;
    function blink(d, count) {
        var el = $(this);
        $.fx.interval = 0;
        return el.each(function (i, elem) {
            var elem = $(elem);
            elem.data("count", count);
            return elem.fadeTo(d, "0", "linear", function () {
                elem.fadeTo(d, "1", "linear", function () {
                    elem.data("count", --count);
                    return (elem.data("count") !== 0 && !elem.data("stop") 
                           ? elem.blink(d, elem.data("count")) 
                           : elem.stop(true, true).data("stop", false))
                })
            })
        }).promise("fx")
    };
}(jQuery));
```

---

```
// e.g.,
var selected = $("div")
, button = $("button:first")
, stop = $("button:last");

selected.on("click", function (e) {
    // start `$.fn.blink` , log returned `promise` on stop
    $(this).blink(750, 10).then(function (el) {
        console.log(el, el.queue(), el.data());
    })
});

button.on("click", function () {
    // unbind `click` event
    selected.unbind('click')
    .promise().then(function (el) {
        el.fadeOut(500);
    });
});

stop.on("click", function () {
    // stop animation
    selected.data("count", null).data("stop", true).clearQueue()
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/33ptL9do/

Comment: Good idea, but the OP is looking for a solution when CSS animations are not available, and the blink plugin falls back to chaining `animate` calls.