# Performing a 'for loop' on an element to blink

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm currently trying to make an element blink 5 times with a loop so that I can replace current code. And this *has* to be replaced by a loop for requirements of class. My current code is

```
    $(function(){

      setTimeout(function() {
      $(".blink").animate({opacity:0},700,"linear",function(){
        $(this).animate({opacity:1},700);
        $(this).animate({opacity:0},700);
        $(this).animate({opacity:1},700);
        $(this).animate({opacity:0},700);
        $(this).animate({opacity:1},700);
        $(this).animate({opacity:0},700);
        $(this).animate({opacity:1},700);
        $(this).animate({opacity:0},700);
        $(this).animate({opacity:1},700);
        });
      }, 1000);
});
```

My last trial of using a loop on this function was

```
$(function(){

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      setTimeout(function() {
      $(".blink").animate({opacity:0},700,"linear",function(){
        $(this).animate({opacity:1},700);
        });
      }, 1000);
    }
});
```

But it's only blinking one time... I have a feeling it's because "i" needs to be some place in the function, but I have yet to have success with any placements. Thanks

Comment: if your browser support list allows it you can use css animations. it is IE10+

Comment: This can return useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605698/text-blinking-jquery

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454687/is-there-a-way-to-control-flow-of-promises-in-linear-call-order , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381524/jquery-using-individual-blinking-text-counters , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691022/jquery-dynamically-change-webkit-animate-time-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increment the timeout delay using `i` as a multiplier

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
      $(".blink").animate({opacity:0},700,"linear",function(){
         $(this).animate({opacity:1},700);
      });
  }, 1500 * i);
}
```

Or set up a recursive function

```
function blink(counter){   

      $(".blink").animate({opacity:0},700,"linear",function(){
         $(this).animate({opacity:1},700,function(){
            counter ++;
             if(counter < 5){
              // start over
              blink(counter);
             }  
         });

     });  

}
```

use

```
blink(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that a better and more efficient way would be to use CSS3 animation to blink element:

https://jsfiddle.net/91gmkxrt/

Then you will need just simple jquery code to blink element

```
$('#box').addClass('blink');
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have put the loop around the `setTimeout`, just put it where the repetitive statements were. And you even don't need that `animate` callback, as animations are queued by jQuery automatically. Just go for

```
$(function(){
  setTimeout(function() {
    var els = $(".blink");
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      els.animate({opacity:0},700,"linear").animate({opacity:1},700);
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```